# Using PyCharm 4.5 professional, I am unable to get `run with coverage` to generate coverage details

Tags: pycharm

Using PyCharm 4.5 professional, I am unable to get `run with coverage` to generate coverage details, I'm sure I am missing something, but I am unsure what at this time.

PyCharm settings:

[image]

Issue also occurs with `Use bundled coverage.py` checked.

Running with coverage does not display any options, nor does it display the coverage window per [JetBrain's help](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/viewing-code-coverage-results.html).

Running manually with `coverage run --source='.' manage.py test polls` results in data being collected and viewable via `coverage report` which outputs the following:

```
C:\Users\RobertH\PycharmProjects\mysite>coverage report
Name                               Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------------------
manage.py                              6      0   100%
mysite\__init__.py                     0      0   100%
mysite\settings.py                    18      0   100%
mysite\urls.py                         3      0   100%
mysite\wsgi.py                         4      4     0%
polls\__init__.py                      0      0   100%
polls\admin.py                         9      0   100%
polls\migrations\0001_initial.py       5      0   100%
polls\migrations\__init__.py           0      0   100%
polls\models.py                       17      1    94%
polls\tests.py                        55      0   100%
polls\urls.py                          3      0   100%
polls\views.py                        38     15    61%
------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                158     20    87%
```

I've also ready through the help available at JetBrains (linked above).

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was running my main deployment with coverage *not* the test class with coverage as is intended.

Running `tests.py` with coverage resolves the issue.